# How to obtain the sign of a Number in ActionScript 3.0?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a variable of type Number, and i like to obtain the sign (if is '-' i like to have -1 and if '+' i like to have 1). So, i made this:

```
var sign = Math.abs(n) / n;
```

But, there is any other way? Better than this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll be in trouble if n == 0... how about this:

```
var sign = n < 0 ? -1 : 1;
```

Comment: dang, beat me by 15 seconds :P

Comment: Does not account for 0, ergo not useful as (e.g.) a sorting compare func, which is the most obvious need for this.

Answer (score 8):

That will give you an error if n is zero.

The brute force method:

```
function sign(num) {
  if(num > 0) {
    return 1;
  } else if(num < 0) {
    return -1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Or, for those with a fondness for the conditional operator:

```
function sign(num) {
  return (num > 0) ? 1 : ((num < 0) ? -1 : 0);
}
```

Comment: I like the second approach, it's much cleaner and it deals with the possibility of n being 0.

Comment: the sign of 0 is + not 0, so: return (num < 0) ? -1 : 1; 
Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2):

You could also do this:

```
var sign = (n>=0)?1:-1;
```

Using what's known as the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:).

Answer (score 1):

I use this:

```
return (number < 0 && -1) || 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your number fits in 31 bits then you can use:

```
var sign = 1 + 2*(n >> 31);
```

Would be interesting to know if this is any faster!

Answer (score 0):

Snippet from the code I inherited:

```
function getSign(number:int):int {
    var tmp:String = new String(number);
    if (tmp.indexOf(0) == '-') {
        return -1;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

PS: Please don't use this code. It is a joke

Answer (score 0):

//n = your number
//nSign = sign of your number

nSign = Math.round(Math.sin(n)*-1);

/*
Math.sin returns a number between -1 and 1. 
You must round it to get a non-DEC number. 
That number will be the opposite of what your number is. Multiply it by -1
*/

// or you could just do this

Math.round(Math.sin(/*n*/)*-1)